# web-based query designer

Tags: sql, widget, designer

I remember seeing online a (sql?) query designer tool that looked like the "point and click GUI" that you get in MSFT access (and other similar apps).

It allowed the user to do simple joins and where clauses and select clauses simply by toggling checkboxes, dragging table icons into view and connecting joins by drawing lines.

This link: [Google Image Search Examples](http://images.google.com/images?hl=en&q=sql+designer&btnG=Search+Images&gbv=2) has examples.

The output was the SQL in plain text.

If anyone knows of a web-based GUI that works like this, that can be plugged into a web CMS, please link and discuss here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe [WWW SQL Designer](http://code.google.com/p/wwwsqldesigner/) will suit you. See [online demonstration](http://ondras.zarovi.cz/sql/demo/?keyword=default).

Comment: Yea, that's awsome ! In fact, it's really terrible ;)